# Proving that $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, functions, proof-verification, magma

Let $X$ and $Y$ denote [magmas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_%28algebra%29), and suppose $f : X \rightarrow Y$ is homomorphism. Then I think that for all $A,B \subseteq X$, we have $f(A+B)=f(A)+f(B).$ However, I'm not happy with my:

*Proof.* The following are equivalent.

1. $y \in f(A+B)$
2. $y = f(a+b)$ for some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$
3. $y = f(a) + f(b)$ for some $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.
4. $y \in f(A)+f(B)$.

Its the final step that's bothering me. How do we know that $3 \leftrightarrow 4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methinks you most likely failed to break it down into enough little pieces to wrap your mind around.

Suppose that there exist $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ such that $y = f(a) + f(b)$. Then $f(a) \in f[A]$ and $f(b) \in f[B]$, so $y\in f[A]+f[B]$.

Suppose that $y \in f[A]+f[B]$. Then there exist $p\in f[A]$ and $q\in f[B]$ such that $y = p + q$. By the definitions of $f[A]$ and $f[B]$, there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ such that $f(a)=p$ and $f(b)=q$. But then $y = f(a) + f(b)$ as desired.

Comment: Yep, that's utterly convincing. Nice one!